# Drawing an animated gif over another animated gif without flickering?

Tags: java, image, graphics, gif, bufferedimage

I'm trying to make a small game with some animated gifs, now I have one animated gif for the background, and one for the player, which moves around. But my problem is, the player gif is flickering alot, it's very annoying, and it's something that needs to be fixed. This is my drawing code. The background draws fine, without flickering, it's just the "playerimage"

```
    public void drawBuffer(){
    Graphics2D b = buffer.createGraphics();

    b.drawImage(background, 0, 0, null);

    b.drawImage(playerimage, player.getX(), player.getY(), null);

    b.dispose();
}
```

I hope you can help me.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).  Since this example requires 2 animated GIFs, you might **hot-link**  in the source, to [starzoom-thumb.gif](http://pscode.org/media/starzoom-thumb.gif) & [plnttm.gif](http://1point1c.org/gif/thum/plnttm.gif) off my sites.